# Is this condition $ \Phi=2\pi \frac mn =B \ell^2 $ correct for the magnetic flux per plaquette in 2D square lattice?

Tags: magnetic-fields, solid-state-physics, gauss-law, lattice-model, lattice-gauge-theory

We have a 2D square lattice with the lattice constant $\ell$, and put it in a homogeneous magnetic field $B$. We are looking for the magnetic unit cell. As we know we get a periodic unit cell only when the flux through a single plaquette ($\Phi$) is a rational function of the flux quantum ($2\pi$), i.e. $\Phi=2\pi \frac mn$ and the unit call contains $n$ plaquettes.

My question is can I claim that this flux per plaquette should be equal to $B \ell^2$ as well? that is $   \Phi=2\pi \frac mn =B \ell^2  $?

Comment: What do you mean by $\Phi$ if not $B\ell^2$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in a 2D square lattice with lattice constant $\ell$ in a uniform, out-of-plane magnetic field $B$ , the flux per lattice plaquette $\Phi$ is defined to be $B\ell^2$. If we adopt the standard Landau gauge in which the vector potential is given by $\mathbf A = Bx \hat y$, then the Aharanov-Bohm phase acquired by hopping counterclockwise around one plaquette is

$$\gamma := \frac{e}{\hbar}\oint \mathbf A \cdot d\mathbf r = \frac{e}{\hbar}\big(Bx \ell - B(x-\ell)\ell\big) = \frac{eB\ell^2}{\hbar}$$
The fact that this is not generically a multiple of $2\pi$ is related to the fact that a single plaquette is not a suitable unit cell.  However, if it so happens that $B\ell^2 = \frac{p}{q} \frac{2\pi\hbar}{e}$ for some integers $p$ and $q$ (which we assume to be relatively prime), then we could arrange for the Aharaonov-Bohm phase to be $\gamma = 2\pi p$ by choosing an appropriate cluster of $q$ plaquettes to constitute the "magnetic" unit cell. We then define $\Phi_0 \equiv 2\pi \hbar/e$ as the quantum of magnetic flux, and $\Phi\equiv B\ell^2$ to be the magnetic flux per plaquette; the aforementioned requirement then becomes $\Phi = \frac{p}{q}\Phi_0$.